# Find dependencies in a python source/script

Tags: python, dependencies, abstract-syntax-tree

I have a bunch of simple scripts in Python with simple expressions[1] like :

```
C = A+B
D = C * 4
```

I need to execute them, but most importantly I need to know what are the objects I depend on; in the previous case, the object *A* and *B* are outer dependencies. Eg. given i have the former code in a var called *source*, i wanna be able to:

```
deps = { "A" : 1 , "B": 2}
exec source in deps
```

so it's strictly necessary to know how to build the dict *deps*.

I've lurked into the *ast* Python module but I had no clue.

---

[1] simple math aggregations, to an extent `for` cycles, nothing more.

Comment: I guess you could be naughty and catch the first few NameErrors

Comment: I was naughty enough to not mention that I'm doing exactly like @JakobBowyer suggested ;)

Comment: An AST isn't enough.   Without a full AST, full name resolution, and serious data flow analysis, you won't be able to make this work for anything but really trivial scripts.   Because Python is a dynamic language, even serious data flow analysis may not provide decent answers.   If you are willing to constrain your "Python" code to be very simple, you may be able to build an analyzer which is reliable.  Your problem is that your users won't pay any attention to the constraints you'll impose.  So unless the user is just you, you're unlikely to get a good result.

Comment: Thank you @IraBaxter, I'm well aware of what you assert; I'm already considering dataflow solutions: I'm building a graph of those scripts...

Comment: What is the precise description of what you need to allow in your "simple" expressions?  Without that constraint, you can't get any useful advice.

Comment: @IraBaxter you are right, my "simple expressions" is too vague: other math statements I would like to use some while/for statemetns and imports. A major constraint is that all the deps/results are in uppercase.

Comment: Here's a "dependency" (data flow graph) for a C program that satisifies your definition of "simple" (Its an  iterative program to compute Fibonacci) http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/C-dataflow-example.jpg     Not simple, and not easy to produce.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can tokenize Python source code using the [tokenize](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tokenize.html) module from the standard library. This will allow you to find all variable names used in the script.

Now suppose we define a "non-dependency" as any variable name that comes immediately before an `=` sign. Then, depending on how simple your script code really is (see the Caveats below), you may be able to determine the variable names which are not non-dependencies this way:

```
import tokenize
import io
import token
import collections
import keyword

kwset = set(keyword.kwlist)
class Token(collections.namedtuple('Token', 'num val start end line')):
    @property
    def name(self):
        return token.tok_name[self.num]

source = '''
C = A+B
D = C * 4
'''

lastname = None
names = set()
not_dep = set()
for tok in tokenize.generate_tokens(io.BytesIO(source).readline):
    tok = Token(*tok)
    print(tok.name, tok.val)
    if tok.name == 'NAME':
        names.add(tok.val)
        lastname = tok.val
    if tok.name == 'OP' and tok.val == '=':
        not_dep.add(lastname)

print(names)
# set(['A', 'C', 'B', 'D'])
print(not_dep)
# set(['C', 'D'])

deps = dict.fromkeys(names - not_dep - kwset, 1)
print(deps)
# {'A': 1, 'B': 1}
```

---

**Caveats**:

- If your scripts contain statements other than simple
  assignments, then `names` may become populated with undesired
  variable names. For example,

  ```
  import numpy
  ```

  would add both `'import'` and `'numpy'` to the set `names`.
- If your script contains an assignment that makes use of left-hand
  side tuple unpacking, such as

  ```
  E, F = 1, 2
  ```

  then the naive code above will only recognize that `F` is not a
  dependency.

Comment: Thank you very much! That's a start ;)

I guess, if I get my coworkers to write those scripts with "variables" all uppercase and not using single line multiple assignments I could use it ;)

Comment: Or convince your coworkers to write runnable code that makes dependencies explicit. A function perhaps?

Comment: Also, as far as `exec source in deps` is concerned, it does not matter if `deps` contains keys for variable names which are not dependencies. The `source` redefines them anyway. So, for example, if you are bug-testing by generating random values to use in `deps`, then it is okay if your definition of dependency is overly broad.

Comment: You're right, @unutbu: actually I would like to use what's supposed to be in the `deps` variable to check for existence of those variables in a graph of variables (the topic gets broader....)

The scripts come from a grammar conversion tool I've written with ANTLR; they could (rarely) be edited by "coworkers" who know nothing of the topics here discussed ;)...

Comment: Thanks, Giupo for the suggested edit regarding `keyword.kwlist`. I've edited my post to include it.